# CATIA v5 under wine, screen flickers

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon

I'm a fairly novice Ubuntu user and this is the first time I use this website. Currently I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 dual-boot (together with Windows 7) installation on my Dell Inspiron 1545 Laptop configuration. The sole reason I still haven't migrated fully to Ubuntu is that, as an engineer I have some special needs in terms of software. I'm using a program called CATIA v5 for my work and I have successfully installed a v5R19 version using Wine 1.5. The installation runs smoothly, with one very very annoying issue which prevents me from being able to do my work. I experience screen flickering when using my program, almost constantly. I took a few steps to fix the problem, non of them helped;

- Adjusted the graphics card settings both for maximum performance and appearance (I have ATI Radeon series 4300 chip, with proprietary drivers running, flgrx AMD catalyst control centre)
- Installed latest updates for my OS.
- Adjusted the program visual settings any way I could think of
- Followed instructions for proper installation here --> http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16156&iTestingId=50899
- I was searching how to fix the issue for a long time now, with no success, nobody seems to either have it or bother to fix it

I have a basic understanding of how to use a terminal and the syntax involved, but since I'm no specialist in the area, I struggle with fixing this myself. I know its hard to find the solution to an issue such as this one, which I guess is a case one in a million, but I'm ready to actively communicate with anyone who can help me out, and supply you with the information you need to work this out. I reach the conclusion that the problem is either located in the way Wine handles the program or the OS itself. I read somewhere that Windows handles this graphics flickering faster, and users simply can't feel it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank You!
Best regards, Ventsy

Answer (score 0):

From [leonexis' post in ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1145963&p=9476476#post9476476):

> If you get a black screen for a moment when you run 'xrandr' from a console, then this might actually not be a Wine bug, but a problem with the video card driver. I have seen it on both Intel and ATI drivers. See [Wine Bug #15214](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15214).
>
> There is a workaround to this issue:
>
> 1. Start Wine's Registry Editor
> 2. Navigate to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\X11 Driver". You may need to create X11 Driver.
> 3. Create a new key called "UseXRandR" and set it to "N".
>
> That should prevent Wine from using XRandR and hopefully fix the annoying black flicker. More useful registry entries for Wine can be found on the Wine Wiki page [UsefulRegistryKeys](http://wiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and thanks for starting to contribute. The forum post you are referring to is fairly old. Plus the linked Wine bug report is even older and was marked invalid, since the devs and that OP agreed the problem was not with Wine but with the graphics card drivers, not with Wine.

Answer (score 0):

write this into the Windows Registry

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\X11 Driver]
"ClientSideGraphics"="no"